# Hook to make a copy of a file at locationA to locationB if the file at location A changes in master branch

Tags: git, github, hook

I have a single github repo with 2 servers that get deployed separately. I am creating a data.json file in serverA and need an exact copy of that same data.json in serverB (another location in the same repo).

Is there a way to ensure that if anyone makes changes to what's in data.json, and commits it to master (or any branch), that this new copy of data.json will get copied over to the other location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup in `repoA` a [content filter driver in a `.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_filter_code).

See [Pro Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion):

[image: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/clean.png]

More specifically, a "`clean`" filter would be called automatically on git commit, and could then perform the necessary script (like for instance an scp) in order to copy the file to `repoB` new location.